# Слияние в пользу определенной ветки

Tags: git

Допустим я нахожусь в ветке `dev`. Ввожу команду `git merge new_change`, после этого появляется много участков в коде по типу этого:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
            message_copy = {'filepath': filepath, 'guid': guid}
=======
            message_copy = {"filepath": filepath, "guid": guid}
>>>>>>> new_change
```

Как мне сделать слияние таким образом, что при возникновении подобных проблем они решались в пользу `dev` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если под термином "подобные проблемы" понимаются любые конфликты, то у команды git merge есть параметры -Xours и -Xtheirs, позволяющие автоматически разрешать конфликт в пользу "нашей" или "их" версии соответственно.

Например: git merge -Xours new_change

Но я настоятельно не рекомендую их использовать в автоматическом режиме.